# How to ignore unit test when condition meets?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I was wondering if there is an annotation or way to only execute test if pre-conditoin meets?
I have a situation where some tests are relevant until a specific date is met. 
I use JUnit, Mockito.
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by using Assume.

In below shown example, I want to check status in case if `precondition==true` and I want to assert that exception is thrown in case of `precondition==false`.

```
@Test
public final void testExecute() throws InvalidSyntaxException {
    Assume.assumeTrue(precondition);  // Further execution will be skipped if precondition holds false
    CommandResult result = sentence.getCommand().execute();
    boolean status = Boolean.parseBoolean(result.getResult());
    Assert.assertTrue(status);
}

@Test(expected = InvalidSyntaxException.class)
public final void testInvalidParse() throws InvalidSyntaxException {
    Assume.assumeTrue(!precondition);
    CommandResult result = sentence.getCommand().execute();
}
```

Hope this helps to you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html) class

> A set of methods useful for stating assumptions about the conditions
>   in which a test is meaningful. A failed assumption does not mean the
>   code is broken, but that the test provides no useful information. The
>   default JUnit runner treats tests with failing assumptions as ignored.

so at the start of your test you can write

```
Assume.assumeThat("Condition not true - ignoreing test", myPreCondition);
```

and JUnit will ignore this test if `myPreCondition` is false.

Comment: The only thing you have to be careful of is that the Assume class will not give you any sort of failure/ignored indicator (when running on Maven at least).  This means that you'll have to have some way of identifying tests that were skipped if this sort of thing matters to you.